# Attempting to convert command output file to csv in python

Tags: python, csv

I am working on a program that i want to convert output files from a linux command line operation into csv's that I can do math on/with. The files are traceroute output files that look like this

```
traceroute to ip (ip), # hops max, # byte packets
1 ip (ip) time ms time ms time ms
2 ip (ip) time ms time ms time ms
3 * * *
etc
```

And i need the first line ignored, and the rest of the lines split up like this

```
1, ip, ip, time, time, time,
2, ip, ip, time, time, time,
etc
```

I don't necessarily need the "ms" removed during the conversion, i can work around them still being in the csv, but it is essential that i can have each hop on its own line with the address it passed through and the TTL of each packet. The traceroute output files will also be varying in length, depending on how many hops the user generating the files ran traceroute for.

I've got both files open, the input .out file and the output .csv file, and my previous attempts used various attempts to find and replace characters to reproduce the lines with commas added to split up the values. I tried simply replacing the space in between each item with a comma using

```
infiledata = infile.read()
infiledata = infiledata.replace(' ', ',')
write = csv.writer (outfile, delimiter=',')
write.writerow(infiledata)
```

This resulted in every character in the file getting separated by a comma, and the output csv had one character per line.

I'm not especially experienced in python so I'm getting mental blocks as to what is actually happening here, and how to change/replace things to get it to do as I need. Any help at all would be appreciated. It also doesn't necessarily have to convert them to csv. if there is still a way I can do things like finding averages and max/min per hop with the data as it is, then that would also work as a solution.

Comment: `writerow()` expects the argument to be a sequence of fields for a single row. You're giving it a string containing the entire file. Since a string is a sequence of characters, it puts each character in its own field in the CSV.

Comment: Instead of replacing characters in the string, I recommend that read each line one at a time and break it into the pieces you need. Take a look at the `split()` method to help with this. You might also want to use a regular expression to get the pieces of each line that you want. Then you can assemble those pieces into a CSV file. For example, you could put them into a dictionary for each line and then use csv.DictWriter to write each line to the CSV file.

Comment: `infiledata` is treated as an *iterable*  See https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#csv.csvwriter.writerows